# SQL Server - Error updating rows in SSMS via a multi-table view

Tags: sql-server, view, ssms, sql-server-2019, dml

I'm designing a database back-end where users will manage the data through a view layer using the "Edit Top 200 rows" option in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

For simple, single-table views, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` all work fine.

For complex, multi-table views, `INSERT` and `DELETE` are ok but `UPDATE` fails:

[image]

If I manually run an `UPDATE` SQL statement on the complex view, it works fine, which suggests that the view and trigger are working as expected.

Any ideas on why the `UPDATE` fails with the "Edit Top 200 rows" feature in SSMS?  Is there a way to get the generated SQL when editing through this tool?

**View**

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_Country AS
SELECT 
  cnt.Country_Id, 
  cnt.Country_Name, 
  cnt.Country_Code, 
  r.Region_Code, 
  cur.Currency_Code
FROM dbo.Country cnt
INNER JOIN dbo.Region r ON cnt.Region_Id = r.Region_Id -- Get region info
INNER JOIN dbo.Currency cur ON cnt.Currency_Id = cur.Currency_Id; -- Get currency info
```

**Trigger**

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_Country_update ON dbo.vw_Country 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE AS
BEGIN

  -- Do some validation first (removed in snippet)

  -- Update base table
  UPDATE dbo.Country
  SET Country_Code = ins.Country_Code,
    Country_Name = ins.Country_Name,
    Currency_Id = cur.Currency_Id,
    Region_Id = r.Region_Id
  FROM inserted ins -- New values
  INNER JOIN deleted del ON ins.Country_ID = del.Country_ID -- Old values
  INNER JOIN dbo.Country cty ON ins.Country_Id = cty.Country_Id -- PK field
  INNER JOIN dbo.Currency cur ON ins.Currency_Code = cur.Currency_Code -- Get Currency Id
  INNER JOIN dbo.Region r ON ins.Region_Code = r.Region_Code -- Get Region Id
  WHERE ins.Country_Code <> del.Country_Code
  OR ins.Country_Name <> del.Country_Name
  OR ins.Currency_Code <> del.Currency_Code -- Currency_Code is alternate key
  OR ins.Region_Code <> del.Region_Code -- Region_Code is alternate key
END
```

**Table**

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.COUNTRY (
  -- General
  COUNTRY_ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  CURRENCY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  REGION_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  COUNTRY_NAME NVARCHAR(100),
  COUNTRY_CODE NVARCHAR(5),
  -- Temporal
  LAST_UPDATED_BY_USER AS (SUSER_SNAME()),
  CREATED_BY_USER NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT (SUSER_SNAME()),
  VALID_FROM DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL 
    DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME(),
  VALID_TO DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL 
    DEFAULT CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999' AS DATETIME2),   
  PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (VALID_FROM, VALID_TO),
  -- Constraints
  CONSTRAINT PK_COUNTRY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (COUNTRY_ID),
  CONSTRAINT UC_COUNTRY_CODE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (COUNTRY_CODE),
  CONSTRAINT UC_COUNTRY_NAME UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (COUNTRY_NAME)
)
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.COUNTRY_history))
```

Comment: I just would not use that half-baked UI to update a regular table, never mind a complex view with triggers. That has been my advice since at least 2009, probably earlier, but [that's when I wrote this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers).

Comment: Should "UPDATE dbo.COUNTRY" be "UPDATE cty" so that it updates the rows joined to ins.Country_Id? Otherwise, I believe it will try to update all country rows independent of the rows referenced by inserted.  And if the trigger is handling more than one update, the trigger may try to apply each update to all rows resulting in conflicts.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point.  I updated the code with your suggestion, but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Aaron, I don't disagree with you - the "Edit Top Rows" UI is not that great.  But it does give our non-technical folks a basic way to manipulate their data in the absence of a real UI and without having to write their own DML.  Do you know how to find out what SSMS is doing under-the-covers with these `UPDATE`s?